# Go YAML unmarshal to custom type - how to convert?

Tags: go, types, yaml, assertion

I am trying to unmarshal a YAML to a structure with multiple fields, some of them with custom types. One of those types is simply

```
type customType string
```

However, if I try to assign a string value, to that field, I get an error similar to this:

```
cannot use result["a"].(string) (comma, ok expression of type string) as customType value in assignment
```

If I try to do a type assertion directly to `customType`, it still doesn't work:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is string, not main.customType
```

I can get it to work if I just convert the type, but I end up with something like this:

```
a = customType(result["a"].(string))
```

So my question is - is there a more... elegant/idiomatic way of accomplishing this?

I have some basic sample code [here](https://go.dev/play/p/eid9ZMG5WEC).
[Edit: updated the sample code to make it more clear that the YAML may contain multiple value types ]

Thank you!

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/liQhAsG8iFs

Comment: @mkopriva - not an option. Unlike the sample code, the original YAML is more complex, with multiple types. So I need to keep `result` as `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: A more elegant / idiomatic way is to model your data with a struct, with matching field types.

Comment: @icza point taken. A bit more difficult in my case (I cannot really predict the YAML structure in advance - some fields may be missing, and additional fields may be present). But definitely not impossible. I see what you mean, and I will keep it in mind. Thank you!